# how to parse string from the array of objects in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an array of objects named customer details which conations country: id, country is a field in customer table which has a relationship with the country table. currently, I am getting the id in the form field when listing the data through a reactive form. I need to parse the int and get the name from the child country table.

**Response:**

```
accountsEmail: "s@s.com"
address1: "b"
country: 1
createdAt: "2020-05-05T05:08:54.858Z"
createdBy: null
deletedAt: null
deletedBy: null
fax: ""
id: 134
```

i want to get parse this country:1 to Afghanisthan

CountryList response

```
createdAt: "2020-04-02T12:35:52.205Z"
 id: 1
 name: "Afghanistan"
 updatedAt: "2020-04-02T12:35:52.205Z"
```

Comment: do you have a country list, please share it's format as well

Comment: added that @ShlokNangia

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach

```js
var obj = {
accountsEmail: "s@s.com",
address1: "b",
country: 1,
createdAt: "2020-05-05T05:08:54.858Z",
createdBy: null,
deletedAt: null,
deletedBy: null,
fax: "",
id: 134
}

var countryList = [
{createdAt: "2020-04-02T12:35:52.205Z",
 id: 1,
 name: "Afghanistan",
 updatedAt: "2020-04-02T12:35:52.205Z"
 }
]

obj.country = countryList.find(c=> c.id == obj.country).name

console.log(obj)
```

This is just for single customer , on the same grounds you can do this for multiple customers